# SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread with Django 2.2.2 and ipdb

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, celery, ipdb

I updated my Django project to version 2.2.2 and now when I call to ipdb for debugging, the server tell me that error. If I go back to Django 2.2.1, the error disappears.

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
June 06, 2019 - 08:19:36
Django version 2.2.2, using settings 'laserapp.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
> /home/lynde/public_html/laserapp/gestion/views.py(192)get_context_data()
    191         import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
--> 192         context = super(ResumeOrderCodeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    193         try:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/lynde/public_html/env/laser/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/lynde/public_html/env/laser/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/lynde/public_html/env/laser/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/lynde/public_html/env/laser/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/lynde/public_html/env/laser/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/lynde/public_html/env/laser/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "/home/lynde/public_html/env/laser/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "/home/lynde/public_html/env/laser/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 585, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lynde/public_html/env/laser/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 570, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "/home/lynde/public_html/env/laser/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 288, in run
    self.run_loop()
  File "/home/lynde/public_html/env/laser/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 294, in run_loop
    next(ticker)
  File "/home/lynde/public_html/env/laser/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 334, in tick
    for filepath, mtime in self.snapshot_files():
  File "/home/lynde/public_html/env/laser/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 350, in snapshot_files
    for file in self.watched_files():
  File "/home/lynde/public_html/env/laser/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in watched_files
    yield from iter_all_python_module_files()
  File "/home/lynde/public_html/env/laser/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 103, in iter_all_python_module_files
    return iter_modules_and_files(modules, frozenset(_error_files))
  File "/home/lynde/public_html/env/laser/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 120, in iter_modules_and_files
    sys_file_paths.append(module.__file__)
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute '__file__'

If you suspect this is an IPython bug, please report it at:
    https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues
or send an email to the mailing list at ipython-dev@python.org

You can print a more detailed traceback right now with "%tb", or use "%debug"
to interactively debug it.

Extra-detailed tracebacks for bug-reporting purposes can be enabled via:
    %config Application.verbose_crash=True

Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lynde/public_html/env/laser/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/history.py", line 780, in writeout_cache
    self._writeout_input_cache(conn)
  File "/home/lynde/public_html/env/laser/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/history.py", line 764, in _writeout_input_cache
    (self.session_number,)+line)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object was created in thread id 140030717908736 and this is thread id 140031011022656.
```

Can somebody know what's the problem there? I'm using django runserver in local machine, with celery and postgresql database.

Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 9):

Try using the `--reload` flag to run runserver. 
`./manage.py runserver --noreload`

It stops the server reloading on code changes but I think avoids the issue you're having.

Comment: That's work! But, why autoreload is now a problem in Django 2.2.2? It's very strange....

Comment: Looks like it was caused by this patch: https://github.com/django/django/commit/5bf2c87ece216b00a55a6ec0d6c824c9edabf188 - fixing this issue https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30479

Comment: Worked for me as well. Should be accepted answer. @LyNDe

Comment: Worked for me, although inconvenient that I have to restart my app. Thanks a bunch! This should be accepted.